# iCloud file download status using ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey not working

Tags: swift, url, swiftui, uikit, icloud

I am trying to check the download status of my url using resourceValues(forKeys:). This is my code

```
if let status = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [URLResourceKey.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey]) {
 if status.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey == .current {
  print("File download complete.")
 }
}
```

This code worked before but now Xcode says "Value of type 'URLResourceValues' has no member 'ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey'" and all I am able to get from status is some thumbnailDictionary. Can anyone tell me what is happening here? Am I making some silly mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong property on `URLResourceValues`:

```
if let values = try? url.resourceValues(forKeys: [.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatusKey]),
   let status = values.ubiquitousItemDownloadingStatus {
    if status == .current {
        print("File download complete.")
    }
}
```